# jquery laravel get ajax parse respone

Tags: jquery, get, laravel-4

i am trying to parse a JSON response returned from a controller action. My Javascript code is as below:

```
$('#searchform').submit(function(e){
    var keyword = $("#q").val();
    $.get('search',$(this).serialize(),function(data){
        var data_obj = $(data);

            var output="<ul>";
            for (var i in data_obj) 
            {
                output+="<li>" + data_obj[i].name + ",  " + data_obj[i].id + "</li>";
            }
            output+="</ul>";

            $('#content').html(output);

});
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

i am able to successfully parse the data , but the html displays data and  lot of li tag containing word "undefined" like below

```
john, 11
doe, 14
robert, 15
undefined, undefined
undefined, undefined
, undefined
undefined, undefined
, undefined
, undefined
, undefined
```

i am unable to understand why i am getting the above result? i want only to get the data returned from response which is actually the top three rows. I am new to JQUERY . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's JSON why are you wrapping it in jQuery ?

```
$.get('search',$(this).serialize(),function(data){
    var data_obj = $(data); // won't work ?
    ......
```

set the proper dataType, and it will be parsed with JSON.parse by jQuery

```
$.get('search',$(this).serialize(),function(data){
    var output="<ul>";
    for (var i in data) {
        output+="<li>" + data[i].name + ",  " + data[i].id + "</li>";
    }
    output+="</ul>";

    $('#content').html(output);
}, 'json'); // dataType
```

and with proper element creation:

```
$.get('search',$(this).serialize(),function(data){
    var ul = $('<ul />');

    $.each(data, function(i, value) {
        ul.append( $('<li />', {text : value.name + ', ' + value.id}) );
    });

    $('#content').html(ul);

}, 'json'); // dataType
```